# Formatting phone numbers in BigQuery

Tags: sql, postgresql, google-bigquery

I want to calculate total order from each customer grouping on their phone number, but the problem is the phone number's format is messy. (I choose grouping by their phone number because sometimes the name is different, it might be their full name or just nick name)

Here's an example

```
+-------+--------------+----------+------------+
| Name  | phone_number | Order Id | Order Type |
+-------+--------------+----------+------------+
| Andy F| 08212345     |        1 | A          |
| Andy  | 821345       |        2 | A          |
| Andi F| 08212345     |        3 | B          |
| Chris | +7712345     |        4 | A          |
| Cris  | 7712345      |        5 | B          |
+-------+--------------+----------+------------+
```

The problem is, the local numbers starts with `0` but sometime there's phone number that didn't include the number `0` as you can see like `Andy` phone number. It has the same phone number but one didn't start with `0`.

And another problem is, when it's foreigner number, sometimes its already include the `+` code sometimes it didn't. Just like `Chris`, one is `+77` another is `77`.

The output that I wanted is like this, so then I can group by their phone number

```
+-------+--------------+----------+------------+
| Name  | phone_number | Order Id | Order Type |
+-------+--------------+----------+------------+
| Andy F| +628212345   |        1 | A          |
| Andy  | +62821345    |        2 | A          |
| Andi F| +628212345   |        3 | B          |
| Chris | +7712345     |        4 | A          |
| Cris  | +7712345     |        5 | B          |
+-------+--------------+----------+------------+
```

Is there anyway to format all of these numbers?

I usually used `REGEXP_REPLACE(TRIM(phone_number),r'^8','+62') AS phone_number`, but it's only for 1 criteria.

Can I use `regexp_replace` when there's more than one criteria?

Comment: How can we tell that `821345` needs to be prefixed with `+62`, while `7712345` should just take `+`?

Comment: that's what i'm asking, all of local numbers either starts with `082xxxxx` or `82xxxx`. others is foreign numbers that only just take `+`.

Answer (score 1):

One method is a `case` expression:

```
(case when phone_number like '082%'
      then concat('+6282', substr(phone_number, 4))
      when phone_number like '82%'
      then concat('+6282', substr(phone_number, 3))
      when phone_number like '+%'
      then phone_number
      else concat('+', phone_number)
 end)
```

This seems to match the logic in your question.  However, there might be other cases as well.

Comment: thanks a lot!! I had `case` expression in mind but got stuck, never use `substr` before.